# Array of Objects in OOP

Tags: java, object

I have written a class like this -

```
class foo
    {
       int t, b;
       foo(int a, int b)
          {
              this.a = a; this.b = b
          }
       foo(){}
    }
```

now I want to create an array of objects. what is the difference between this two-line-

```
foo[] ab = new foo[100];
foo ab[100] = new foo[100];
```

Comment: And unrelated: class names go UpperCase in Java. Also note that you should better follow consistent bracing strategies.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that the second line will not even compile, as that is invalid syntax in Java. So besides that there is "sense" in repeating that `100` information, that part only belongs on the right hand side of the statement.

On the left hand side, you have the **type**. The type is "array of foo". The number of elements within an actual instance of that type is "runtime only". It is not reflected in the type.

Answer (score 0):

foo[] ab = new foo[100];

Above line of code will create a reference variable that hold the reference to object containing declaration of 100 variables of type foo (Class name though should be in Initial Caps)

foo ab[100] = new foo[100];
This line of code will throw compilation error as you are declaring an array  variable with size.

You can replace this line with creating a new object and asisgning to variable per index. 
ab[0] = new foo(1,2);
This way you can create the object and assign to your array indexes.